# Trying to add a menu to my Material.io's MaterialToolbar and it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm breaking my head wis an error.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScanningChoice">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_box_24"
        app:title="Scanare"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/scan_specific_item"
        />



</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/butonScanare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="64dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/scanare"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_a_photo_24" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/table_main"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:contentDescription="@string/details_about_object"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

 </menu>
```

[image]

The issue seems to be with the app:menu="@menu/scan_specific_item"

When I remove it it looks like this:

[image]

but it lacks the search icon I desire to use.

I've been stuck with this problem for about 5 hours.

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Did you create "scan_specific_item" in the @menu folder?

Comment: @SlothCoding yes, I did